# Populate RecyclerView Item with data from two database tables

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app where the user can register a set of incomes and expenses for a particular asset you have (bitcoin, litecoin, bank account, etc) for that you have to create an account for every of those assets. Now, I have a cardView for every account where you can see a balance of the current month. I need to populate this card in the RecyclerView Adapter whith data from the account table and the Records (incomes and expenses) table. Here is an image:

[image: Account CardView]

What can I do?

I am using Room library, LiveData and ViewModel components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If account, income and expense tables could be joined so the problem is solved by creating a data class containing resulted table columns. if there are columns with the same name rename them in the query and add the required field to the data class.

This is an example in which I have a question table which could have many answers but for some reasons, I need to show answers with question title in recycleview so for this reason I joined child table with it's parent table.

```
@Dao
interface EvaluationDao  {


@Query("select EVALUATION.*,QUESTION.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION,QUESTION.BRIEF_DESCRIPTION_ENG ,QUESTION.CATEGORY_ID,QUESTION.ID AS Q_ID  ,QUESTION.HELP_LINK ,QUESTION.QUESTION_TITLE,QUESTION.QUESTION_TITLE_ENG ,QUESTION.WEIGHT   from EVALUATION INNER  join QUESTION on QUESTION.ID= EVALUATION.QUESTION_ID where  EVALUATION.CLINICAL_UNIT_ID  = :unitId  AND   QUESTION.CATEGORY_ID  IN (select QUESTION_CATEGORY.ID from QUESTION_CATEGORY where QUESTION_CATEGORY.MODULE_NAME = :moduleName) order by QUESTION.QUESTION_TITLE_ENG")
fun getEvaluations4CinicalUnits(moduleName: String, unitId: String): Flowable<List<EvaluationWithQuestion>>
 }
```

this is the equivalent data class

```
@Parcelize
class EvaluationWithQuestion() : Parcelable {

@Embedded
var evaluation: Evaluation? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
var categoryId: Int = -1

@ColumnInfo(name = "QUESTION_TITLE")
var questionTitleFa: String = "" 

@ColumnInfo(name = "QUESTION_TITLE_ENG")
var questionTitleEn: String = ""

@ColumnInfo(name = "HELP_LINK")
var helpLink: String = ""

@ColumnInfo(name = "WEIGHT", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
var weight: Double? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "BRIEF_DESCRIPTION")
var briefDescriptionEn: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "BRIEF_DESCRIPTION_ENG")
var briefDescriptionFa: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "Q_ID")
var questionId: Int = -1

@Ignore
var rowNum: Int = -1
}
```

Comment: I think that I am going to read the examples in the Room documentation, I will perform an inner join and return a single list of info, then give that to the adapter. Thank you!